# Newbie help - with vlookup

Tags: google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I am new to Google Sheets and need some help in validating data from one sheet into another. I have a list of item on other sheets and just want to validate on my master sheet whether that item is on each of my two other sheets.

On my master sheet (Delivered List), I have a list of approx 5k items and want to check to see which items are on my two other lists, Live Yes and Live No.

Here is the Delivered List sheet.
[!Delivered List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffyp4.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffyp4.png)

In column K, I need a formula to check Live Yes to see which items in column D are on that sheet.
In column L, check Live No list for same.

Here are the screenshots of Live Yes and Live No.

[image: screenshot of Live Yes sheet]

[image: screenshot of Live No sheet]

I hope this is clear enough and if anyone can help me with this.
thanks tremendously!
AJ

I tried copying a similar formula from another example, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for google sheets VLOOKUP is `VLOOKUP(search_key, range, index, [is_sorted])`. So in this case, the key you're looking for is the `Item` column. And you're looking for it in the `Item #` column on the delivered list sheet.

I don't have sheets up right now, but my guess is that, for example, the first cell of "On Delivered List" for "Live Yes" would be `=VLOOKUP(C3,'Delivered List'!D:D,FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try put this in K3 of your 'Delivered List' sheet.
This should do what you want.

```
=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(LOOKUPVALUE,
 IF(LOOKUPVALUE="","",
  SPLIT(
   BYROW(LOOKUPVALUE,LAMBDA(ITEM,
    XLOOKUP(ITEM,'Live Yes'!$C:$C,'Live Yes'!$C:$C,"UNFOUND")<>"UNFOUND"&","&
    XLOOKUP(ITEM,'Live No'!$C:$C,'Live No'!$C:$C,"UNFOUND")<>"UNFOUND"
   )),","
  )
 )
)('Delivered List'!$D$3:$D))
```